# Piwik goals(checkout steps)

Tags: matomo, goal-tracking

I am looking for a way to create checkout steps goal in Piwik with the same functionality as it's in Google analytics(Goal Funnel). As far as I have managed with this - Piwik can do that but it doesnt provide separating those steps(only contains/regex for URL). Maybe someone knows a solution for this?

P.S. Using Piwik 1.10.1

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed to solve this by creating goal for each unique checkout step and calling `trackPageView()` on frontend for each step